# debug SIGSEGV signal handler function

Tags: debugging, assembly, exception, x86, disassembly

I made small assembly code about registering signal handler.

```
.section .data
.set SIGSEGV, 11
.set SA_SIGINFO, 4

.section .bss   
.lcomm my_sigaction, 140 # size of sigaction struction is 140

.section .text
.global main

myhandler:
    nop
    push %eax
    pop %eax

main:
    # Registring signal handler for SIGSEGV
    movl $myhandler, my_sigaction           # fill sa_handler field 
    movl $132, %edi                         # fill sa_flags field
    movl $SA_SIGINFO, my_sigaction(,%edi,1) # SA_SIGINFO  designate that whenever signal appears, run the signal handling function.

    # Call sigaction(int, const struct sigaction *, struct sigaction *)
    pushl $0                                # 1st param : oact
    pushl $my_sigaction                     # 2nd param : act
    pushl $SIGSEGV                          # 3rd param : sig
    call sigaction
    addl $12, %esp

    jmp 0x11223344                         # Segmantation fault
```

When I execute compiled binary, `myhandler` worked well.

However ... when I tried to debug this, **gdb** just stoped after ***SIGSEGV*** signal occurred.
So I could not reach to `myhandler` with **gdb**..

**Question.

How can I debug `myhandler` function, which runs after SIGSEGV signal?**

***PS 1.*** I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44356298/how-to-debug-a-c-program-with-signal-handler-in-gdb), but setting follow-process-mode wasn't helpful in my case. ;(
***PS 2.*** I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414860/how-to-debug-program-with-signal-handler-for-sigsegv), but after asserting `handle SIGSEGV nostop`, gdb infinitely emits the "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault" message when SIGSEGV occured...

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the handler, and `c`ontinue after the debugger caught the error?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Even though I set the bp on `myhander`, gdb stopped after SIGSEGV. So I could not debug this signal handler function.

Comment: And after the GDB caught the crash, did you use the `continue` command to continue execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem myself.

```
pwndbg> b myhandler
pwndbg> handle SIGSEGV pass
Signal        Stop  Print   Pass to program Description
SIGSEGV       Yes   Yes Yes     Segmentation fault
pwndbg> handle SIGSEGV nostop
Signal        Stop  Print   Pass to program Description
SIGSEGV       No    Yes Yes     Segmentation fault
pwndbg> r
Breakpoint myhandler
```

Setting `pass` and `nostop` on SIGSEGV signal worked!
After SIGSEGV occured, I can still debug binary on gdb.

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question!